# Python Telegram bot doesn't respond to case-insensitive commands - any suggestions?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

How to make my Telegram bot understand the case insensitive characters?

Bot responds to lowercase handler messages, however it doesn't respond anything to a case insensitive command. I do not see any errors either. Also, I remember reading in Telegram API Docs that says handler messages are case insensitive.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'hello'])
def send_welcome(message):
    """Sends a welcome message to the user."""
    command = message.text.casefold()  # Convert the command to lowercase
    print(command)

    if command == '/start':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello! How can I help you?")
    elif command == '/hello':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi! How are you?")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Unknown command.")

bot.polling()
```